# trying to connect to access database using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ms-access

I am a beginner to javascript. I am trying to connect to an access database with the help of a javascript function and wrote the below code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function AddRecord() 
{
var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\TWP Alternate Press.accdb'");
adoRS.Open("Select * From COMMODITIES", adoConn, 1, 2);
console.log('Database Connected');
document.write("c");
adoRS.Close();
adoConn.Close();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Connect" onclick="AddRecord()">
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to connect to "COMMODITIES" table in the database. But when I click the "Connect" button no action is being performed. What am I doing wrong here.

from firebug I am seeing the below error:

```
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined    
var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
```

**I also tried in Internet Explorer, but the log statement is not being printed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `ActiveXObject` you are using , this is exclusively Microsoft technology. That means this code snippet will only work in Internet Explorer. Since you mentioned that you were using firebug , i am assuming that you were using Firefox.

Try Internet Explorer or better you use IndexedDB which modern, robust, cross browser compatible.

Comment: Even in IE, the log statement is not being printed.

Comment: that means ActiveXObject is found but you are facing  some error before reaching the `console.log()` line. 
My guess is that your `Data Source='C:\TWP Alternate Press.accdb'` is not getting the database. Please try 
1. copy the TWP Alternate Press.accdb in to your project root folder.
2. change the name to TWPAlternatePress.accdb for safety.
3. change this 
`adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\TWP Alternate Press.accdb'");` to 
`adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='/\TWPAlternatePress.accdb'");`

Comment: try using .mdb database file rather than .accdb.
I have seen many people use .mdb database with activex not accessdb.